# Description of real roots of Kac—Moody algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems, kac-moody-algebras

Let $\Delta$ be a root system associated to a generalized Cartan matrix, $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ its simple roots.

It is known that if $\Delta$ is of finite, affine or hyperbolic type, $\alpha=\sum_i k_i\alpha_i$ is a real root if and only if $(\alpha,\alpha)>0$ and $k_i(\alpha_i,\alpha_i)/(\alpha,\alpha)\in\mathbb{Z}$ for all $i$.

In a more general setting, every real root $\alpha$ is of the form $w_i\beta$, where $w_i$ is the reflection associated to a simple root $\alpha_i$ and $\beta$ is another real root with $\operatorname{ht}(\alpha)> \operatorname{ht}(\beta)$. In other words, there is a height-increasing path of simple reflections from a simple root to $\alpha$.

I guess it is not reasonable to expect that for arbitrary (symmetrizable) GCM there is a criterion in terms of simple roots similar to the one above.

But are there examples on non-hyperbolic indefinite type root systems that admit such an explicit description for the set of real roots?